# Error in Silverlight 4 app: Event handler 'True' not found on class 'MyApplication.MainPage'

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Has anyone ever come across this one?

One second everything works ok, then I get this error out of nowhere. 
It doesn't make sense, and there's no code/xaml out of place.

Bing/Google searches come up empty.

Visual Studio 2010
Silverlight 4 application
VB.NET

Answer (score 3):

Found the problem. If you want to specify that a checkbox is checked, set the IsChecked property to True, and not the Checked property.

This is correct:

Auto Save

This will make your life miserable:

Auto Save

My biggest complaint with Silverlight is this kind of problem. Visual Studio didn't bring me to this line, let alone this property setting. I had to manually comment out code, then individual blocks of xaml to figure it out.

Comment: In Windows Phone 8 dev you get similar problems where the exceptions lead you to arbitrary places!